# Using countdown timer to jump out of while loop Python

Tags: python, time, timer, while-loop, countdown

I'll just get to the code to show you, I'm trying to stop my while loop when my timer is over. Is there a way to do that?

```
from threading import Timer

def run(timeout=30, runs):
    timer(timeout)
    while runs > 0 or over():
        #Do something
        print "start looping"

def timer(time):
    t = Timer(time, over)
    print "timer started"
    t.start()

def over():
    print "returned false"
    return False
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the function `over()` to stop my while loop. Currently, when my time stop, over is returned as false, but it doesn't affect my while loop. I must be doing something wrong.

So what `Timer` object allows me to do is to pass a function param so that when the timer is over, it calls that function, `over()`. As `over()` returns `False`, it doesn't directly affect the while loop in real time. Will I need a callback to implicitly force the `while` to be false or is my method of stopping is completly faulty and will not work.

Answer (score 0):

## Changes

- When your timer expires, you need to change the state so that when `over` is invoked, it will return `True`. Right now, I keep that in global state for simplicity. You will want to change this at some point.
- Also, you had a logic error in your while loop condition. We need to make sure it still has runs *and* is *not* over.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from threading import Timer

globalIsOver = False

def run(runs, timeout=30):
    timer(timeout)
    while runs > 0 and not over():
        #Do something
        print "start looping"
    print 'Exited run function.'

def timer(time):
    t = Timer(time, setOver)
    print "timer started"
    t.start()

def setOver():
    global globalIsOver
    print '\nSetting globalIsOver = True'
    globalIsOver = True

def over():
    global globalIsOver
    print 'returned = ' + str(globalIsOver)
    return globalIsOver

run(100000000, timeout=2)
```

This returns the following after the 2 seconds have expired:

```
...
start looping
returned = False
start looping
returned = False
start looping
returned = False
Setting globalIsOver = True

start looping
returned = True
Exited run function.
```