# How can you make a timer run simultaneously with the rest of the code in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I am making a simple math test for my friend's class. The students will only have 45 seconds to solve each answer. Is there a way to make a timer that will count at the same time as the rest of the code runs and when it reaches 45 stops?

The test looks like this:

```
test = raw_input("How much is 62x5-23?")
if test == '287':
    print "Well done!"
```

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950092/using-countdown-timer-to-jump-out-of-while-loop-python

Comment: Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435211/python-threading-timer-repeat-function-every-n-seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I used once (lifted off some page on the web which is now in the hands of a domain squatter, so no credit where credit is due, sadly):

```
import signal

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass

def timeout(timeout_time, default = None):
    def timeout_function(f):
        def f2(*args, **kwargs):
            def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
                raise TimeoutException()

            old_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
            signal.alarm(timeout_time) # triger alarm in timeout_time seconds
            try:
                retval = f(*args, **kwargs)
            except TimeoutException, e:
                if default == None:
                    raise e
                return default
            finally:
                signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, old_handler)
            signal.alarm(0)
            return retval
        return f2
    return timeout_function

# use like this:
@timeout(45)
def run():
    test = raw_input("How much is 62x5-23? ")
    if test == '287':
        print "Well done!"

# alternatively, pass a value that will be returned when the timeout is reached:
@timeout(45, False)
def run2():
    test = raw_input("How much is 62x5-23? ")
    if test == '287':
        print "Well done!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        run()
    except TimeoutException:
        print "\nSorry, you took too long."

    # alternative call:
    if run2() == False:
        print "\nSorry, you took too long."
```

**EDIT**: probably works on Unix-type OS'es only.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in idle and it didn't work. I am new at Python so a little bit of explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @VagosLabrou are you running Python on Windows by any chance? I don't know if it'll work on Windows (signals are more of a Unix thing).

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows.

Comment: @VagosLabrou that might be the reason why it's not working; I'll update my answer to reflect that.